# How to draw a lines between points and pull those points?

Tags: android, drawing, points

I want to draw the lines between points on the view, and then pull those points upto desired positions even the shape will change.

i know how to draw the line between two points `canvas.drawLine(10, 10, 90, 10, paint);` by using this i can draw the lines between points.

`EDIT` : here i am attaching image for clear explanation, from Paul answer now i am able to draw the lines between points, still have the problem of pulling points...

[image]

Comment: can u plz post the whole code?? coz I badly need this code.... thanks in advance

Comment: plz let me know atleast how to implement this in onDraw() method.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's how it's done. Suppose you have your points, make these global:

```
PointF topLeft = new PointF(10,10);
PointF topRight = new PointF(90,10);
PointF bottomLeft = new PointF(10,90);
PointF bottomRight = new PointF(90,90);
```

What you need to do is make a RectF around each point. The bigger the RectF, the bigger the touch area for the point is.

```
float sizeOfRect = 5f;
RectF topLeftTouchArea = new RectF(topLeft.x - sizeOfRect, topLeft.y - sizeOfRect, topLeft.x + sizeOfRect, topLeft.y + sizeOfRect);
//Do this for the other points too
```

Define some globals to keep track of what the user is doing in onTouch. One int is the corner being touched, and the other four are identifiers for the corners.

```
private final int NONE = -1, TOUCH_TOP_LEFT = 0, TOUCH_TOP_RIGHT = 1, TOUCH_BOT_LEFT = 2, TOUCH_BOT_RIGHT = 3;
int currentTouch = NONE;
```

Now, in your onTouch event, you can check which point your user is touching in like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    switch (event.getAction()) {
    //The user just put their finger down.
    //We check to see which corner the user is touching
    //And set our global, currentTouch, to the appropriate constant.
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        if (topLeftTouchArea.contains(event.getX(), event.getY()) {
            currentTouch = TOUCH_TOP_LEFT;
        } else if (topRightTouchArea.contains(event.getX(),event.getY()) {
            currentTouch = TOUCH_TOP_RIGHT;
        } else if (botLeftTouchArea.contains(event.getX(),event.getY()) {
            currentTouch = TOUCH_BOT_LEFT;
        } else if (botRightTouchArea.contains(event.getX(), event.getY()) {
            currentTouch = TOUCH_BOT_RIGHT;
        } else {
            return false; //Return false if user touches none of the corners
        }
        return true; //Return true if the user touches one of the corners
    //Now we know which corner the user is touching.
    //When the user moves their finger, we update the point to the user position and invalidate.
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        switch (currentTouch) {
        case TOUCH_TOP_LEFT:
             topLeft.x = event.getX();
             topLeft.y = event.getY();
             //The bottom left x position has to move with the top left corner
             bottomLeft.x = topLeft.x;
             //The top right y position has to move with the top left corner
             topRight.y = topLeft.y;
             invalidate();
             return true;
        case TOUCH_TOP_RIGHT:
             topRight.x = event.getX();
             topRight.y = event.getY();
             //The top left y position has to move with the top right corner
             topLeft.y = topRight.y;
             //The bottom right x position has to move with the top right corner
             bottomRight.x = topRight.x;
             invalidate();
             return true;
        case TOUCH_BOT_LEFT:
             bottomLeft.x = event.getX();
             bottomLeft.y = event.getY();
             bottomRight.y = bottomLeft.y;
             topLeft.x = bottomLeft.x;
             invalidate();
             return true;
        case TOUCH_BOT_RIGHT:
             bottomRight.x = event.getX();
             bottomRight.y = event.getY();
             topRight.x = bottomRight.x;
             bottomLeft.y = bottomRight.y;
             invalidate();
             return true;
        }
        //We returned true for all of the above cases, because we used the event
        return false; //If currentTouch is none of the above cases, return false

    //Here the user lifts up their finger.
    //We update the points one last time, and set currentTouch to NONE.
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        switch (currentTouch) {
        case TOUCH_TOP_LEFT:
             topLeft.x = event.getX();
             topLeft.y = event.getY();
             //The bottom left x position has to move with the top left corner
             bottomLeft.x = topLeft.x;
             //The top right y position has to move with the top left corner
             topRight.y = topLeft.y;
             invalidate();
             currentTouch = NONE;
             return true;
        case TOUCH_TOP_RIGHT:
             topRight.x = event.getX();
             topRight.y = event.getY();
             //The top left y position has to move with the top right corner
             topLeft.y = topRight.y;
             //The bottom right x position has to move with the top right corner
             bottomRight.x = topRight.x;
             invalidate();
             currentTouch = NONE;
             return true;
        case TOUCH_BOT_LEFT:
             bottomLeft.x = event.getX();
             bottomLeft.y = event.getY();
             bottomRight.y = bottomLeft.y;
             topLeft.x = bottomLeft.x;
             invalidate();
             currentTouch = NONE;
             return true;
        case TOUCH_BOT_RIGHT:
             bottomRight.x = event.getX();
             bottomRight.y = event.getY();
             topRight.x = bottomRight.x;
             bottomLeft.y = bottomRight.y;
             invalidate();
             currentTouch = NONE;
             return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

What this does is make a rectangle around your point. Imagine drawing boxes around your points in the picture. These are the "touch pads" created by the Rect objects. The size of the rectangle is set by sizeOfRect. In the onTouchEvent, it checks each rectangle object to see if the user's touch is inside the rectangle, signaling an the user trying to touch that point.

Comment: i tried this but still i am unable to understand it properly. can you share any tutorial on this..

Comment: actually i am using one main activity from that i am calling drwaSquare() function for drawing square , i am unable to call touch listeners to that view..

Comment: if you are making a custom View object, you can just override the onTouchEvent method

Comment: i draw square with 4 points ( those 4 are different points) for touch, now i am unable to getting touch on those points....

Comment: i am able to move the line at first time, second time its not working and also those RecF are not going to be change...

Comment: and i am drawing on frame layout is it correct process or not .

Comment: FrameLayout is fine. You need to update the RectF in the onDraw method.

Comment: yes i was updated RectF in the onDraw() it's working fine, how can i drag and drop the total view in the frame layout. bez, i have to create triangle, square, line and circle in the view depends on the user button click. and also place those created views where ever he wants on the view..if did't understand this let me know...

Comment: That's a whole nother piece of work. Post another question for help with that.

Comment: @RajaReddyPolamReddy can u plz post the whole code?? coz I badly need this code.... thanks in advance

Comment: @ZedScio plz help me.. my question is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13302566/draw-line-along-points-using-finger which is similar to your above answer but a bit different.

Answer (score 4):

I think you may be looking for the [Path](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path.html) class:

> The Path class encapsulates compound (multiple contour) geometric
>   paths consisting of straight line segments, quadratic curves, and
>   cubic curves. It can be drawn with canvas.drawPath(path, paint),
>   either filled or stroked (based on the paint's Style), or it can be
>   used for clipping or to draw text on a path.

See [this tutorial](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/how-use-canvas-your-android-apps-part-2) for examples of `canvas.drawPath`

Comment: I don't think those exist but they're easy to create. Just draw small squares where the points are in the middle of the squares and then do hit testing to see which one gets hit and perform dragging operations on the point. Actually, lol, that is a bit complicated but not really that hard to get right.

Comment: i was edited my Question with image, i am able to draw lines by using path, problem with touch listeners...

Answer (score 2):

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Paint.Style;
import android.graphics.PointF;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

public class TestView extends View
{

    private Paint paint;
    private PointF startPoint, endPoint;
    private boolean isDrawing;

    public TestView(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    private void init()
    {
        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.RED);
        paint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(2);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        if(isDrawing)
        {
            canvas.drawLine(startPoint.x, startPoint.y, endPoint.x, endPoint.y, paint);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
    {
        switch (event.getAction())
        {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                startPoint = new PointF(event.getX(), event.getY());
                endPoint = new PointF();
                isDrawing = true;
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                if(isDrawing)
                {
                    endPoint.x = event.getX();
                    endPoint.y = event.getY();
                    invalidate();
                }
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                if(isDrawing)
                {
                    endPoint.x = event.getX();
                    endPoint.y = event.getY();
                    isDrawing = false;
                    invalidate();
                }
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: your code working like redraw the line from what point you want to drag, i don't want to redraw just expanding the line with another line stay at previous point..

Answer (score 2):

EDIT:

You indeed need to use [Path](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path.html) class in android. Sorry I couldn't come up with a code snippet. But here's something to get you started off.

When you draw a line - `canvas.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2, paint);` your starting point is `(x1,y1)`. now, if you need to pull the line from any end, you need to first fix the other end. Say you pull from `(x2,y2)` . So `(x1,y1)` becomes constant and you pull from the other end. When using the Path class, first call a `moveTo()` to this fix point. What it does is it gives a point about which the line has to be moved. Then, you can use the `lineTo()` call on the touch events to stretch the line accordingly. A lot of tweaking will be needed. But this is what can get you started. Sorry I couldn't come up with a snippet, little short on time. See the documentation of the Path class. You might find some more helpful things.

---

EDIT:

About adding touch listeners to points:

Suppose you have a line from `(x1,y1)` to `(x2,y2)`.

Now to get touch listener for a point, you can add an onTouchListener to your whole view.

```
final View touchView = findViewById(R.id.touchView);
    touchView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
               if(event.getX() == x2 && event.getY() == y2)
               {
                  //you know that you have clicked on the rear end of the line,so now you can do your dragging stuff.
                  if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                       //you know user has clicked in order to draw
                       //redraw the existing line with black color to remove it
                       paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                       canvas.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2, paint);
                       //reset the paint object
                       paint.setColor(Color.WHITE); 
                       //now use moveTo() and lineTo() to attain the functionality of dragging on your Path object
                       path.moveTo(x1,y1);
                       path.lineTo(event.getX(),event.getY());
                  }else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){
                       path.lineTo(event.getX(),event.getY());
                  }else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                  }
       }  
               return true;
        }
    });
```

This is just an idea, I still didn't get the opportunity to test it. I hope it helps.

Comment: this is just for drawing with finger, read my question if you did't get let me know.

Comment: ohh..ok..you want that first user clicks on a point,then clicks on another point,and then there is a line between those points,right?

Comment: no, already i have a line between two points now i want to drag one point to extend line without changing another point.. like changing the triangle size..

Comment: let me just tweak around with this and let you know in a while.

Comment: @RajaReddyP please see the edits. I have tried something,don't actually know if it will work out.

Comment: Actually i am using custom class for creating drawing from activity to that custom view i am unable to call touch listeners. unable pass drawing functions if i use like what you told..

Comment: i completed upto creating points and draw the lines between points by your guidance, pending part is touch listeners only...